problems with GPU after upgrade to noble
I recently upgraded to 24.04. display resolution is on minimum settings and I cannot change it. Also everything is so slow, so I tried to install amdgpu-install --usecase=graphics with latest version found here https://repo.radeon.com/amdgpu-install/latest/ubuntu/noble/. This did not work and gave errors. Then I switched from 6.8.0-45-generic to the older kernel version 6.8.0-40-generic as it is the latest hwe kernel for 22.04. amdgpu-install --usecase=graphics finished without problems. But after rebooting I still have the same problems. Has anyone gotten the GPU driver to work on 24.04?
Output of inxi -G:

> Graphics:
  Device-1: AMD Navi 21 [Radeon RX 6800/6800 XT / 6900 XT] driver: N/A
  Display: wayland server: X.Org v: 23.2.6 with: Xwayland v: 23.2.6
    compositor: gnome-shell v: 46.0 driver: X: loaded: radeon
    unloaded: fbdev,modesetting,vesa dri: swrast gpu: N/A
    resolution: 3840x1080~60Hz
  API: EGL v: 1.5 drivers: kms_swrast,swrast
    platforms: gbm,wayland,x11,surfaceless,device
  API: OpenGL v: 4.5 vendor: mesa v: 24.2.0-devel renderer: llvmpipe (LLVM
    18.1.7 256 bits)
  API: Vulkan v: 1.3.275 drivers: N/A surfaces: xcb,xlib,wayland


you are still using the radeon driver, you may need to add it to the blacklist

Ok, it was a secure boot issue. I really don't know why it got enabled. But after disabling it everything works again like it should. With secure boot enabled the driver could not load...

Windows often turns back on features it thinks it needs after updates to its OS.
